# ruleflow-group vs agenda-group in Drools 6.5

Tags: drools, kie

I am trying to create two independent groups of rules in Drools 6.5 and I can't figure out what's the usecase for the ruleflow-group and agenda-group strategies. They both seem similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading the documentation ...

2.6.4. RuleFowGroup and AgendaGroups are merged

These two groups have been merged and now RuleFlowGroup's behave the same as AgendaGroups. The get methods have been left, for deprecation reasons, but both return the same underlying data. When jBPM activates a group it now just calls setFocus. RuleFlowGroups and AgendaGroups when used together was a continued source of errors. It also aligns the codebase, towards PHREAK and the multi-core explotation that is planned in the future.